# Too many concurrent connections opened Microsoft Graph API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I'm currently running a web application that uses Microsoft Graph's API and we encountered the following message today which severely impacted our application, for a whole day:

```json
"error": {
    "code": "ErrorTooManyObjectsOpened",
    "message": "Too many concurrent connections opened., The process failed to get the correct properties.",
    "innerError": {
        "request-id": "removed",
        "date": "2017-12-13T17:01:14"
    }
}
```

*please note that the request-id was removed*

Let me summarize what our web application does.

Basically, we have 2 email folders that we are actively subscribed to, `Junk` and `Folder A`.

If anything hits `Folder A`, we strip the body of the email message and then move the message to `Folder B`. The subscription on our `Junk` folder also strips the body and sends them over to `Folder B`.

Sometimes the webhook subscription service skips messages that may come at the same time, therefore we have 2 cron jobs in our server that run a script and check `Junk/Folder A` for any messages every 5 minutes, therefore my assumption is that the cron job runs about `288*2` times per day. Not counting our subscription to the folders, we usually get around 200-300 email messages per day.

Unfortunately Microsoft's Graph error codes page does not provide us with any explanation about this code. I would really appreciate if anyone can explain what this means and how to avoid it from happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is occurring because your application is exceeding the throttling thresholds.

There are several different throttling metrics that can affect Microsoft Graph requests. For a high-level overview, see the [Microsoft Graph throttling guidance](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/throttling). Since in this case you're hitting Exchange Online via Graph, you can find more specific information from [What throttling values do I need to take into consideration?](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn458789(v=exchg.150).aspx#Anchor_2) in the Exchange documentation.

Architecturally, you are making a lot of unnecessary calls into the API. Rather than having both a subscription *and* a scheduled job, you should use just the webhook subscription and the [`/delta`](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/delta_query_messages) endpoint.

Each call to the `/delta` endpoint gives you a token that can be used to fetch any changes to a given resource since the token was originally issued. So regardless of if 1 email came in or 1,000, you only get the new emails.

Once you're using the `/delta` to find your changes, you then use a webhook only as a "trigger". When you receive the webhook, you can ignore the contents and instead issue a request to `/delta`. This ensures that you capture *every* incoming email even if you didn't necessarily receive separate webhook notifications.

Comment: This link mentions about [graph api rate limits](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/developer/api-limits) for licensed users. Do they apply to guest users too? 
Also it seems the /delta endpoint is not available for all resources. I was searching for such an endpoint for microsoft teams but couldn't find it.
Your inputs would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There is a bug.  After making 500 message move requests, a "cannot copy/move error" occurs. Subsequently, a "429: Too many concurrent connections opened" error occurs.  Most applications miss the first error because you continually get the 429 error afterwards.

If you let the application "rest" for 30 minutes, the throttle resets itself and you can continue on.  I do not think there is a time limit for hitting the 500 moves.  My application did 500 moves after 6.5 hours and then we started getting the error.

And, if you keep trying your move call before the 30 min rest period, it never resets.  Also, in the response, the retry-after is null... so, that doesn't help you.

If you find a work around, please let me know. We are trying a few things like setting the category, then manually moving the messages. I am also investigating making a rule the moves them for us or some other job.  I cannot find a way to execute a rule from the Graph API.

See this link for more information.  Also, the more people who report having this issue, hopefully the sooner it can be resolved. [Outlook API Throttling documentation #144](https://github.com/OfficeDev/outlook-dev-docs/issues/144)

Comment: I hit this problem right now. Although I suppose that's a temporary problem on MS side